# Permutations for time in JSON

Tags: algorithms, javascript, json, loops, combinatorics

Let's say that I have a JSON file like at example below.

How would I go about finding all possible values of item combination ***time sums*** that exist between let's say `00:03:04` to `00:25:55` without finding every single permutation combination that exists and adding them for that set?

For example item 1 and item 3 would be found in that time constraint where their times add together to `00:20:32`.

I have tried to use permutations, but you run into certain drawbacks with more objects. If I go up to 7 objects, it clearly takes me over 13,000 iterations of adding time values together and checking for range constraints.

What can I do to simplify the algorithm?

```
 {
"item1":{"time":"00:18:21"},
"item2":{"time":"00:22:22"},
"item3":{"time":"00:02:11"},
"item4":{"time":"01:34:32"}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting downvotes and close votes.  Algorithms are clearly on topic here.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt this is possibly because question was rather poorly laid out. [Original version](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/344751/1) looked like a code dump followed by hard to read wall of text. I edited it to hopefully better shape

Comment: I've read this 4 times and still don't understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly where you're going wrong is finding *permutations* when you only need to look for *combinations*.  For your example, if item 1 and item 3 are found, you don't need to check later for item 3 and item 1, but your 13,000 number shows that you are.  If you eliminate those duplicate checks, there are only 120 combinations to check for 7 objects.

You can also look for opportunities for pruning.  If `item 1 + item 2` is greater than your max range, you don't need to check `item 1 + item 2 + item 3`, `item 1 + item 2 + item 4`, and so forth.  If you arrange your checks depth-first, it will be easiest to do this pruning.

Comment: It might be worth saying that this is pretty much what [constraint programming libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming#Constraint_programming_libraries_for_imperative_programming_languages) do. You model your problem with constraints (and this one is quite easy to do), and you feed it to a solver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with JSON, unless extracting a few numbers from JSON into an array is a problem for you.

You don't need permutations of the times, you need a subset. In your example of 7 time values, there are 128 possible subsets of these values. So the problem can easily be solved in O (2^n) where n is the number of values; faster if the target time is so small that you only need to consider subsets with few items.

An alternative is an algorithm which takes about O (k), where k is the target time, which will be better if k is small compared to 2^n: Create a bitmap of all totals that can be created using any subset of the first 1, 2, 3, ... items.